# Reg Ex for hyperlinks in comments

Tags: regex, hyperlink, comments

I am trying to find a solution to extract an hyperlink out of every comment which begins with `%`.  My first idea was to use a regular hyperlink regex:

```
^(http|https|ftp)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*[^\.\,\)\(\s]$
```

and some kind of pattern like:

```
%.*
```

so I added them both to:

```
^%.*(http|https|ftp)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*[^\.\,\)\(\s]$
```

But with this pattern I match everything, including the `%` character and multiple spaces.  How can I get **only** the hyperlink inside the comment?

EDIT1:

Here is an example what to parse:

```
% http://www.test.com
```

It is a regular MATLAB Comment and i want to highlight it like a hyperlink to get a more intuitive editor. I am working with Qt 4.7.1 / C++

Thanky for all the answers !

Comment: can you please share sample content ? is within `href` attr of `<a>` tag ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends a little on the language that is executing your regex, but you could try putting the URL part in parentheses:

```
%.*((http|https|ftp)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*[^\.\,\)\(\s])
```

That way you can access it as a group (usually an expression such as `$1`).

Comment: I am using Qt C++ and your expression did the same as mine

Comment: @8472 This is why you need to tell us what language you're doing this in in your OP.

Comment: @8472 How are you executing the regex? can you isolate a group once you execute your expression? maybe if you showed us your code we could figure out how to make it work